# How to sum selected column only

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

If i have [a table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PFQU.png)

With excel formula, How do i sum only selected column for each row? For example, `Day` only (J Column) and `Night` (k Column) only?

Please don't suggest with plus (+). As the table could not be scalable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need little tricky method to get the SUM:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `K2`, fill it Right.

`=SUMPRODUCT(F$2:I$5*(LEFT(F$1:I$1)=K$1))`

**How it works:**

- The trick is to apply **Filter** by matching column headers begin with **D & N**, the **LEFT** function is been used, returns.

`{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE}` for **Day** and `{FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}` for **Night**.

**N.B.**

Reason behind using **LEFT** rather than use complete text, **Day** is, since the Formula if used,

`=SUMPRODUCT(F$2:I$5*((F$1:I$1)=K$1))`

fails to filter Columns and returns `0`, even the Array Formula Also.

- The **SUMPRODUCT**, multiplies by `F2:I5` using *Two-dimensional array* and gets the results.

**N.B.** I've used this tricky method because any standard Formula like,

`=SUM(INDEX(F$2:I$5,0,MATCH(K1,F$1:I$1,0)))`

fails to *Filter* data to **SUM** for *respective Headers* (returns `#N/A` error).

*Adjust cell references as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Yuri,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

If the data is next to each other, select the two rows in the columns and select "AutoSum" from the ribbon, the summed number will appear to the right